# Why does my retrofit code not insert data in the database?

Tags: android, wcf, retrofit2

Why can't my retrofit code insert data in the database? I publish my wcf service on iis and it is working fine fine when I pass parameter in browser.

Here is my interface code:

```
interface ApiInterface {

@POST("client")
Call<client>insert(@Body client cl);
}
```

Here is my model class:

```
 public client(String name, String contact, String addres) {
    this.name = name;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.addres = addres;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

and here is main activity:

```
    textname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    textcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact);
    textpssword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.send);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            client cl=new client(textname.getText().toString(),

textcontact.getText().toString(),textpssword.getText().toString());
            sendNetworkrequest(cl);
        }
    });

}

private void sendNetworkrequest(client cl){

    Retrofit.Builder builder=new 


 Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://192.168.1.20/Service1.svc/").
 addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit=builder.build();

    ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<client> call=apiInterface.insert(cl);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<client>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<client> call, Response<client> 
 response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"compl 
 inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<client> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "some thing went wrng", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Can I pass write format of `baseurl` ?

This is working fine in browser

```
http://192.168.1.20:8080/Service1.svc/insert?name=mehmood&contact=123&addres=lahore
```

is a local published address. insert is a function defined in the wcf service.

Comment: Your insert method is defined in WCF as using http-get, which is usually decorated with the [webget] attribute. So when we construct HTTP request, we should utilize the query string instead of the request body to pass the parameters (attributes of the entity)

Comment: exactly ....    [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke (Method="GET",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate="/insert?name={name}&contact={cont}&addres={addr}")]
        string insert(string name, string cont, string addr); so what i do

Comment: If the constructed http request is POST and attaches a JSON request body, we could define the OperationContract like below,
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method ="POST",RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        String InSertProduct(Product p);
    [DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your example request (http://192.168.1.20:8080/Service1.svc/insert?name=mehmood&contact=123&addres=lahore) is using query parameters to send the fields. But your Retrofit definition seems to put your parameters into the Request Body.

If your Service takes query parameters in a POST Request then you need to do something like this:

```
@POST("/insert")
Call<client> insert( 
    @Query("name") String name, 
    @Query("contact") String contact, 
    @Query("addres") String addres
);
```

It seems odd to post something with query parameters, but maybe you have good reasons 4 that.

By the way, you would actually get your client object as a return type, this is not the request type.

And please rename client to Client. I'm to much of a nerd to not mention it ;)

Comment: thanks for concentration sir....i am new in android ..but a little bit confusion is in this segment. in Call what i do. sory for poor english bcoz its not my native language
    ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<client> call=apiInterface.insert(cl);

Comment: you should change insert function in ApiInterface with one suggested by KnechtRootrecht

Comment: which means instead of retrofit body parameter you must use query param when calling the function.

Comment: ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        client c=new client(name,contact,addres);
        Call<client> call=apiInterface.insert(c.getName(),c.getcontact(),c.getaddres()); it doesnot work